# Visual Studio Test Playlist with relative path

Tags: visual-studio-2015, automated-tests

I have created a test playlist for running my tests in Visual Studio 2015. Playlist file has absolute path (like C:\Application\Test\test1.orderedtest). I want to share my playlist with other developers who will not have the same absolute path for the tests. So I manually changed the absolute path to the relative path in Playlist file. But now visual studio 2015 doesn't find any test in playlist file.
Please suggest how to create the playlist which can be shared.
Thanks in advance!